# Compiled function code objects - passing parameters

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to pass arguments to the __code__ of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874558/how-to-pass-arguments-to-the-code-of-a-function)

I have a code object representing a function. When I call `exec` on the code object, how do I specify a value for the input parameter `p`?

```
def x(p):
    print p

code_obj = x.__code__

exec code_obj
#TypeError: x() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: thankyou, wish my search skills were better.

Comment: Though the best solution is worth to mention here too: `import types; types.FunctionType(code_obj, {})(1)` (because it exists only as a comment, and not even for the accepted answer)

Comment: indeed, I saw that technique and used it in a test which worked well. Ultimately I have heeded the wise words to avoid using __code__ wherever possible and use __import__ instead. But it's an interesting curiosity which has now been satisfied.

Comment: @kosii If the best answer isn't an answer, I suggest you add it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuming the answers and comments from the duplicated:

```
import types
types.FunctionType(code_obj, globals={}, name='x')(1)
```

To work with methods, you can use a function type or an unbound method and then pass an instance as first parameter, or bound the function to an instance:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def f(self, param):
        print self.name, param

# just pass an instance as first parameter to a function or to an unbound method
func = types.FunctionType(A.f.__code__, globals={}, name='f')
func(A('a'), 2)
unbound_method = types.MethodType(func, None, A)
unbound_method(A('b'), 3)
# or bound the function to an instance
bound_method = types.MethodType(func, A('c'), A)
bound_method(4)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the benefit of adding name='x' in the call (your first code block)? I ran this without the name parameter and it worked fine. What's the incentive to have that parameter there?

Comment: It's an optional parameter, I just wanted to show it. It's used for example when you print a function object.