# How to print pass arguments to code object via exec and print in python?

Tags: python

How to print pass arguments to code object via exec and print in python? Below are just few examples to see how things work in a generic case.

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x * y

exec(foo.func_code {'x': 1, 'y': 5}) # This didn't work

def bar():
    return 3*5

exec(bar.func_code) # this got executed but I couldn't print it?
```

Comment: `exec('print(foo(1,5))')`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why do you need to use `exec` exactly? I get the feeling there's a better way to accomplish whatever you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you'll be able to pass arguments to a code object without using "black magic". Why not use `exec("print foo(1, 5)")`?

In your both examples, nothing is printed because `exec` simply executes `xxx.func_code`, but function `foo` and `bar` contain no print statements.

Comment: I understand it contains no print statements but why cant we do something more like print (exec(code_object)) or something like that and how to pass arguments to any function using code_object and exec. That is more of my intention.

Comment: `exec(code_object))` return None, so ` print (exec(code_object)) `  is meaningless. See [Python: How to pass arguments to the __code__ of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874558/python-how-to-pass-arguments-to-the-code-of-a-function) .

Comment: @EmL But technically speaking, `exec(foo.func_code, {'x': 1, 'y': 5})` is not __passing__ arguments.