# How does using '?' for object information work?

Tags: python, function, ipython

I stumbled upon the following syntax in [Python decorator to keep signature and user defined attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746567/python-decorator-to-keep-signature-and-user-defined-attribute):

```
> def func():
...     return "Hello World!"
...
> func?
Signature: func()
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      ~/<ipython-input-8-934f46134434>
Type:      function
```

Attempting the same in my Python Shell, whether 2 or 3, simply raises a `SyntaxError`. So what is this exactly, is it specific to some shells?

Comment: `func` is not a python keyword. It is only defined in a place where you `def func()` as a function.

Comment: This looks like some IPython specific syntax.

Comment: This is specific to the IPython shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an IPython feature, described [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#dynamic-object-info)

> Typing `?word` or `word?` prints detailed information about an object.
> ...
>   Typing `??word` or `word??` gives access to the full information, including the source code where possible. Long strings are not snipped.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons using the `?` character in the pre-packaged Python IDLE shell fails, is because using the `?` is specific to [*IPython*](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#dynamic-object-information):

> Typing `?word` or `word?` prints detailed information about an object. If certain strings in the object are too long (e.g. function signatures) they get snipped in the center for brevity. This system gives access variable types and values, docstrings, function prototypes and other useful information.