# Returning signature of base class when using a mixin

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, mixins

I have a class `B` defined by multiple inheritance.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

class AMixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # do stuff
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class B(AMixin, A):
    pass
```

Basically the mixin class overrides the `__init__` method, but from the point of view of users using class `B`, class `B`'s signature is same as `A`.

Since I am using `*args` and `**kwargs` in the mixin class, then `B`'s initialization is based on `A`'s constructor (functionally).

However, **linters** won't know that and they would think that `B`'s signature is `args` and `kwargs`, which is kind of unhelpful.

I think this is he same problem as letting `inspect.signature` return `A`'s signature (instead of `AMixin`) when inspecting `B`, but now here is what I get when I inspect `B`:

```
from inspect import signature
signature(B).parameters.keys()
# odict_keys(['args', 'kwargs'])
```

How to make it return `['x', 'y']` instead?

Comment: Faced a very similar problem today. I look forward to the answers!

Comment: Maybe you could write a metaclass that walks up the mro and builds an appropriate signature when the type is being created.  I'm not sure how you would store that signature so that `inspect` would access it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, and with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409295/set-function-signature-in-python), I came up with a solution by decorating `class B` as such:

```
from functools import wraps

def BaseSignature(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    # Override signature
    wrapper.__signature__ = signature(f.__mro__[2])
    return wrapper
```

So then `B` is defined as:

```
@BaseSignature
class B(AMixin, A):
    pass
```

and now `signature(B)` gives `<Signature (x, y)>`, and the linter is also working nicely.

Although it works, it is still not ideal for me, because I have tens of those, and not looking forward to add the same decorator to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Class B `__init__` is inherited from `AMixin` class. Even though `AMixin` is calling `super()` with `**args` and `**kwargs`, its `__init__` function can execute any logic as you want. It doesn't make sense for linter to expand on what's being run inside a function.