# Change the signature of a function inside a class via decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I already have a class `poly()`, and a method `get_function()`

```
class poly():
    def __init__(self,n):
        func = ''
        var = []
        for i in range(n + 1):
            func += ('k'+str(i)) + ' * '+ 'x ** ' + str(i) + ' + '
            var.append('k'+str(i))
        func = func[:-3]

        self.func_str = func
        self.var = var
        siglist = var.copy()
        siglist.append('x')
        self.siglist = tuple(siglist)

    def get_function(self, *args):
        return eval(self.func_str)
```

Now what I want to do is to pass `self.siglist` to signature of `get_function` for future usage(`scipy.optimize.curve_fit` needs `__signature__` to do curve fitting)

I ran

```
pol = poly(2)
inspect.signature(pol.get_function)
```

It shows that the signature of that function is `<Signature (*args)>`

But I want to change signature from `*args` to `k0, k1, x`(Stored in tuple `siglist`)

What I found in Python Cookbook is:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect
def optional_debug(func):    
    @wraps(func)    
    def wrapper(*args, debug=False, **kwargs):             
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    sig = inspect.signature(func)    
    parms = list(sig.parameters.values())  
    # what is inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY do ?
    parms.append(inspect.Parameter('debug', inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY, default=False))    
    wrapper.__signature__ = sig.replace(parameters=parms)   
    return wrapper 

@optional_debug
def test(input):
    pass

print(inspect.signature(test))
```

This function is able to change the signature of a function, the result is:

```
(input, *, debug=False)
```

How to pass `self.siglist` to edit the signature if I put the decorator outside the class, and why is there a `*` in the signature after using a decorator to change it?

________________To edit the `__signature__` if a function is not in a class___________

```
def make_sig(*names):
    parms = [Parameter(name, Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
            for name in names]
    return Signature(parms)

def test():
    pass
ls = ('a','b')
test.__signature__ = make_sig(*ls)
inspect.signature(test)
```

get:

```
<Signature (a, b)>
```

But What about it inside a class?

Comment: To answer your two direct questions: 1. you can't (`siglist` is only known on instantiation, and decorators are invoked at definition time); and 2. because you asked for debug to be keyword-only, see e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409295/set-function-signature-in-python