# How can I assign the value of a variable using eval in python?

Tags: python

Okay. So my question is simple: How can I assign the value of a variable using eval in Python? I tried `eval('x = 1')` but that won't work. It returns a SyntaxError. Why won't this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Whatever you are doing you should not use eval.

Comment: Disagree, eval has tons of great uses

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Because `x=1` is a statement, not an expression. Use [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#exec) to run statements.

```
>>> exec('x=1')
>>> x
1
```

---

By the way, there are many ways to avoid using `exec`/`eval` if all you need is a dynamic name to assign, e.g. you could use a dictionary, the [`setattr` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#setattr), <del>or the [`locals()` dictionary](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#locals)</del>:

```
>>> locals()['y'] = 1
>>> y
1
```

**Update**: Although the code above works in the REPL, it won't work inside a function. See [Modifying locals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python) for some alternatives if `exec` is out of question.

Comment: And btw, if you want to change a variable like this, you probably want a dictionary instead.

Comment: Probably will use a dictionary next time I do something like this.

Comment: Python docs say you shouldn't modify `locals()`. (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)  Is there another way to just use assignment without the full evil of `eval()`?

Answer (score 18):

You can't, since variable assignment is a statement, not an expression, and `eval` can only `eval` expressions. Use `exec` instead.

Better yet, don't use either and tell us what you're *really* trying to do so that we can come up with a safe and sane solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use lambda, like this:

```
eval('(lambda x=10: x+2)()')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually put `exec()` command inside `eval()`

So your statement would look like `eval("exec('x = 1')")`

p.s. this is dangerous

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
def assignNewValueToX(v):
    global x
    x = v

eval('assignNewValueToX(1)')
print(x)
```

It works... cause python will actually run assignNewValueToX to be able to evaluate the expression. It can be developed further, but I am sure there is a better option for almost any needs one may have.

Comment: Almost, but I need to dynamically assign the variable name. Thanks though.