# Using variables within strings

Tags: python, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I assign the value of a variable using eval in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python)

i want to assign a value to a variable that is inside of a string using python

so suppose

```
y = 'x  = 5' 
eval(y) # does not work
```

I want something that evaluates this expression so that `x = 5` in python

Comment: Already asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Try `exec` instead:

```
In [8]: y = 'x  = 5'

In [9]: exec(y)

In [10]: x
Out[10]: 5
```

However as with `eval`, I imagine there are security concerns here (see [this article](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/), for instance), so you may want to approach from a different angle if possible. As for why `eval` doesn't work, it is because it is evaluating the string as if it were a Python expression. Therefore when you say `x = 5`, there is no return result. `exec` on the other hand will execute the statement, and in this case it will set `x = 5` in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec` statement for this:

```
exec y
```

(In Python 3, it's a function, not a statement.)

However, you probably shouldn't.  If you do this with user-input text, it is a security risk.  It also can do things you might not expect, depending on what scope you exec the code in.  See [the documentaton](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) for more info.  There is usually a better way to do whatever you want to do than using `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#exec).

```
y = 'x  = 5' 
exec(y)
print x
```