# Set the name of a python object/variable with a string

Tags: python, string, function, keyword, argument-passing

Most people will probably say this is a bad idea.  I want to use the content of a string as the name of a variable.  I want to accomplish the dreaded:

```
s = 'x'
x = 1
```

where the variable name `x` comes (somehow?) from the string `s`.

To answer the "why?", say I have a global default value for `x` that I want the option of overriding in a function.  But:

```
x = 0
def f(**kw):
    print x
f(x=1)
```

prints `0` not `1`.  If I could use the strings in kw.keys() to reassign `x` (or any other globally set variables) then I'd be happy.

I realize that this works for reassigning `x` in `f`:

```
x = 0
def f(x=x):
    print x
f(x=1)
```

But I want to do this for cases where there are MANY variables in my namespace that I might at some point want to override without rewriting every function definition in my module.

Comment: Why not keep a dict of these "global" state variables?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [exec](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec)

```
>>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> s = 'x'
>>> exec(s + " = 1")
>>> print x
1
```

See also: [How can I assign the value of a variable using eval in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python)

After a little experimentation, this also seems to work:

```
>>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> s = 'x'
>>> globals()[s] = 1
>>> print x
1
```

Comment: There is almost never a reason to use eval or exec. You can use getattr or setattr instead, in this case.

Comment: For my own learning, how would you use setattr in this context?

Comment: Your edited answer is one way to directly set a global variable. But I usually reserve globals for constant (read-only) values that are truly global. If you need to keep state then use a class and instance variables.

Comment: @JesseVogt Thanks for the direct answer to the original question.  I appreciate the other posts saying that `exec` is a bad thing to rely on, but it's good to know it's there in a bind.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider using the `global` keyword (http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

I recommend taking a look at [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python#4693385) as well.

Also, as promanow suggested, using a global mutable object might be a better approach.

However, keep in mind that having large amounts of code that *might* modify or depend on a mutating global is very scary idea, from a maintenance perspective. Tread carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment via function arguments is not obvious and therefore is not considered Pythonic (Python is not C). See `import this`.

The cheap way that I've done flat configuration is through a global partial dict:

```
In [1]: from functools import partial
In [2]: config = partial(dict)
In [3]: def f(x=None):
   ...:     print x or config.x
   ...:     
In [4]: config.x = 'foo'
In [5]: f()
foo
```

Something to this effect *is* obvious, readable and therefore much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to do this for cases where there are MANY variables in my namespace that I might at some point want to override without rewriting every function definition in my module.

It sounds like you want a class:

```
class Foo(object):
    x = 0
    def f(self):
        print self.x

my_foo = Foo()
my_foo.x = 1
my_foo.f()
```

Comment: I'm sure you're right that this is the best big picture answer.  I know I need to learn how to use classes in my code.  So considering that I'm doing all this in a module that has a lot of different interacting functions, then I guess I should just wrap all these related functions in a class to have more control of the parameters they all share.  I guess that would avoid or at least help with the problem of all these functions having to pass parameters back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for creating dynamically custom modeling databses for targets of interest from one global database:

```
DBs = ["Target_1_DB","Target_2_DB","Target_3_DB"]

for db in DBs:
    print(db)    
    exec_str = "Modeling_DB_Base = " + db
    exec(exec_str)
    #s = "Modeling_DB_Base"
    #globals()[s] = db
    print(Modeling_DB_Base.shape)
```

using the commented-out globals() results in error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following solution:

```
s = 'x'
locals()[s] = 1
```