# Class object: adding attributes to class based on an input list

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Say I have the following simple Class object

```
class TEST:

    def __init__(self, project = 'ABC', scenarios = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]}):

        self.project = project
        self.scenarios = scenarios


P = TEST(project = 'ABC', scenarios = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})

print(P.scenarios)

{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
```

**What I want:** Using the example above, I want to be able to specify:

```
P = TEST(project = 'ABC', scenarios = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C': [7,8,9]})
```

and be able to return the following output

```
In [2]:P.A
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]:P.B
Out[4]: [4, 5, 6]

In [3]:P.C
Out[4]: [7, 8, 9]
```

That is, I want to automatically add the dictionary keys as attributes and have them return the values of the dictionary.

**What I've tried**: This is similar to how a Pandas DataFrame automatically adds the column names as attributes and returns the series. I've tried combing through the backend code there but no luck.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764088/set-the-name-of-a-python-object-variable-with-a-string) was helpful, but I wasn't able to get anywhere with it because I wasn't able to figure out a way to add it as an attribute (e.g. self. + scenarios.keys(), etc)

Comment: Warning: you are using a mutable default value for `scenarios`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just update the instance's `__dict__` with `scenarios`:

```
class TEST:
    def __init__(self, project='ABC', scenarios=None):
        self.project = project
        self.scenarios = scenarios or {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
        self.__dict__.update(self.scenarios)

>>> P = TEST(project='ABC', scenarios={'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})
>>> P.A
[1, 2, 3]
>>> P.B
[4, 5, 6]
>>> P.C
[7, 8, 9]
```

BTW, this might not be your real code, but [avoid mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) unless you are sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

First, have a look at this tiny usage of `setattr()` function which is used to define properties of modules, classes etc.

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> setattr(a, "prop1", 10)
>>> 
>>> a.prop1
10
>>> 
>>> setattr(a, "increment", lambda x: x + 1)
>>> 
>>> a.increment(110)
111
>>>
```

Finally, you can try like this.

> **a** is like **self**
>
> **prop1** is like **feature** i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`
>
> **scenario** is like **10** i.e. `[1, 2, 3]`, `[4, 5, 6]`, `[7, 8, 9]`

```
>>> class TEST:
...     def __init__(self, project = 'ABC', scenarios = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]}):
...         self.project = project
...         for feature in scenarios:
...             scenario = scenarios[feature]
...             setattr(self, feature, scenario)
... 
>>> 
>>> P = TEST(project = 'ABC', scenarios = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C': [7,8,9]})
>>> 
>>> P.A
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> P.B
[4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> P.C
[7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

You can get mini help on your Python Interactive Terminal using `help(setattr)` which shows below.

> Help on built-in function setattr in module builtins:
>
> setattr(obj, name, value, /)
>      Sets the named attribute on the given object to the specified value.
>
> setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to ``x.y = v''