# How to create incremental variables from a list which may vary in number of items. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie. I have created a list from a .csv file:

```
 h = [2.3, 1.4, 4.5, 4.5, 1.4, 2.3]
```

The number of items in the list varies (from 2 to 36) depending on the .csv file.
I want to create incremental variables from the list like this (so I can use them later in the code):

```
 L1 = 2.3
 L2 = 1.4
 L3 = 4.5
 L4 = 4.5
 L5 = 1.4
 L6 = 2.3
```

My problem is that the number of items in the list from the .csv file varies and I have tried using the increment and enumerate methods, but I cannot make it work at all.

Comment: what do you mean by *incremental variable*?  Why can't you use indexing to access elements of list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try to explain my ignorance which is a self-referencing situation. :-) I want to loop through the list and create a unique variable for each item. But since I don't know how many items are in the list, I don't know how many unique variables to create. I am thinking I should loop through the list and create the variables, but I don't know how to make each variable unique.

Comment: Short answer: you shouldn't. Use a dict or something similar. Have a look at the duplicate for reasons why and ideas of what to do instead.

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish with *sequential variables* that indexing can't accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it would help to create a dict from the list.
You can use this dict comprehension statement.

```
h = [2.3, 1.4, 4.5, 4.5, 1.4, 2.3]

result = {f"L{index+1}": value for index, value in enumerate(h)}

> {'L1': 2.3, 'L2': 1.4, 'L3': 4.5, 'L4': 4.5, 'L5': 1.4, 'L6': 2.3}
```

And you can get the number which you need by specifying the key. For example:

```
print(result["L1"])

> 2.3
```

Comment: Thank you DenisOH, this will work for my situation. I apologize to all the others to whom I did not explain well enough what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining one variable for each element in the list, you can simply get the value of each element via its index:

```
h[0] # first element of the list (2.3)
h[1] # second element of the list (1.4)
h[2] # third element of the list (4.5)
# etc
```

which you can use like `print(h[0])`.

`len(h)` gives you the number of elements in `h`. The last element in the list has index `len(h)-1` (5 in your example).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you stick with the list for storing data , and access it via `h[i]`

However , you can still have your wish using exec:

```
for i,x in enumerate(h):
    exec(f'L{i}=x')
```

Please note that the first L will be L0 , change the above code if you want to start with 1.

Comment: I get this error:     eval(f'L{i} = x')
  File "<string>", line 1
    L0 = x
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Nevermind I can't use eval (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python)