# alternatives to using exec in running code dynamically

Tags: python

I'm building my own Python REPL and will need to execute statements typed by the user. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python) that discusses using `setattr` to run assignment statements dynamically. Are there equivalents for executing other types of statements like loops and defining classes, or is `exec` the only way to do so?

Comment: If the entire goal is to run arbitrary user-supplied code, you might as well use `exec`. Just make sure you understand the consequences of that goal - for example, if you're planning to offer this as an online service, you'll have to run the interpreter in some kind of secure sandbox and not trust it in any way.

Comment: The point of using things like `setattr` instead of `exec` is to *avoid* the possibility of running untrusted code.

Comment: I understand. And that's exactly what I am looking for to avoid calling exec to run other type of user code like while loops.

Comment: not exactly sure this is relevant and would help but, could you try using docker to containerize each code run by the user? would that offset some of the issues of using ```exec```?