# Why does eval() throw a syntax error here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

**I'm new to programming and I'm trying to understand why eval fails in this particular case. Any help would be much appreciated.**

````
eval('st=int(st)')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    eval('st=int(st)')
  File "<string>", line 1
    st=int(st)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Comment: are you looking for `exec('st=int(st)')`?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python

Comment: Eval can only have expressions (not statements i.e. assignment makes it a statement).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Should I delete this question as it essentially asks the same thing as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python

Comment: Mark it as duplicate and close