# how to create variable names dynamically and assigning values in python?

Tags: python

I would like to assign variable (matrices names) dynamically and assigning some values.

Below is the sample code I am trying. The expected output is mat1 and mat2 containing values 1 and 1 respectively.

```py
stri = "mat"

for i in range(1,2):  
     "_".join([stri, i])=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in RunOrVeith's answer, a Dict is probably the right way to do this in Python. In addition to `eval`, other (non-recommended) ways to do this including using exec or setting local variables as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python)

```
stri = "mat"

for i in range(1,3):  
    exec("_".join([stri, str(i)])+'=1')
```

or locals,

```
stri = "mat"

for i in range(1,3):  
    locals()["_".join([stri, str(i)])] = 1
```

This define `mat_1 = 1` and `mat_2 = 1` as required. Note a few changes to your example (`str(i)` and `range(1,3)` needed, for python3 at least).

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you don't assign actual variables this way.
Instead just create a dictionary and put the values in there:

```py
stri = "mat"
data = {}
for i in range(1,2):  
     data["_".join([stri, i])] = 1
```

If you really want to do that (which I again do absolutely not recommend, because no IDE/person will understand what you are doing and mark every subsequent access as an error and [you should generally be very careful with eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)):

```py
stri = "mat"

for i in range(1,2):  
     eval(f'{"_".join([stri, i])}=1')
```