# Is it possible to "dynamically" create local variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables, memory, local, instantiation

Is it possible to create a local variables with Python code, given only the variable's name (a string), so that subsequent calls to "'xxx' in locals()" will return True?

Here's a visual :

```
>>> 'iWantAVariableWithThisName' in locals()
False
>>> junkVar = 'iWantAVariableWithThisName'
>>> (...some magical code...)
>>> 'iWantAVariableWithThisName' in locals()
True
```

For what *purpose* I require this trickery is another topic entirely...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is warned against but it can be done in python 2.x using the exec function - but not in 3.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python

Comment: "For what purpose I require this trickery is another topic entirely..." - and is **infinitely more important**. Ask the question that pertains to what you really want to do, not the question that pertains to how you think you want to do it.

Comment: Karl: MitchellSalad notes in a comment below that he's using a dictionary instead- a good choice.

Comment: You rarely want to do this; usually a dictionary holding your 'variables' as keys is *much* more practical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, you could use `exec`:

```
print 'iWantAVariableWithThisName' in locals()
junkVar = 'iWantAVariableWithThisName'
exec(junkVar + " = 1")
print 'iWantAVariableWithThisName' in locals()
```

Of course, anyone will tell you how dangerous and hackish using exec is, but then so will be any implementation of this "trickery."

Comment: Heh.  We even used very similar sentences -- even down to the use of italics! -- to indicate that the OP probably shouldn't be doing this.  I guess there really should be one obvious way to (explain why you shouldn't) do it..

Comment: Yes, but yours sets junkVar to None, and mine sets it to 1. That makes all the difference. :) +1 to yours

Comment: This would only work in Python 2, as it disables the locals optimisation. *Your function will run slower* when you do this. It won't work at all in Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

You can play games and update locals() manually, which will sometimes work, but you shouldn't.  It's specifically warned against in the docs.  If I *had* to do this, I'd probably use exec:

```
>>> 'iWantAVariableWithThisName' in locals()
False
>>> junkVar = 'iWantAVariableWithThisName'
>>> exec(junkVar + '= None')
>>> 'iWantAVariableWithThisName' in locals()
True
>>> print iWantAVariableWithThisName
None
```

But ninety-three times out of one hundred you really want to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For this specific instance, the exec call is looking a lot more tasty than managing a dictionary, because of the huge number of variable names my code produces. Can you perhaps elaborate a little more on what you mean by exec "sometimes" working? EDIT: A dictionary will work fine. No need to elaborate. :)

Comment: What "sometimes" works is updating the locals dictionary, not using exec. For example: `locals()["myvar"] = 1`. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) say: "Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: @MitchellSalad: no, I meant that updating locals() -- i.e. locals()['junkVar'] = 99 -- is slightly dangerous, and anti-recommended..  exec should work, security problems notwithstanding.  I'm not sure I share your tastes, though: the *more* variables I had, the more likely I'd be to wrap them into a dictionary.

Comment: If there are a huge number of variable names, that is _all the more reason_ to use a dictionary, so you're not cluttering up your namespace. What possible reason could you have to use locals? ETA: Aha- now I see you've come to the same conclusion. And I've seen that DSM continues to be my doppelganger.

Comment: Okay, I'm done.  Clearly @DavidRobinson can channel my views perfectly on this subject. :^)

Answer (score -2):

No need to use exec, but locals()[string], or vars() or globals() also work.

```
test1="Inited"

if not "test1" in locals(): locals()["test1"] = "Changed"
if not "test1" in locals(): locals()["test2"] = "Changed"

print " test1= ",test1,"\n test2=",test2
```

Comment: Try that in a function and it won't work.