# Set class (self) variables from variables?

Tags: python, variables

This is poor programming practice, yes, I know, but these scripts are purely mine and this technique would ease my coding a lot.

Right now, I have an SQLite database containing a set of key-value pairs representing configuration directives for my script. The script itself is a class which I import into other scripts.

So, right now, when I want to access a config variable, I call something like:

```
myLib.myClass.getConfigVariable("theItemIWant")
```

This gets really ugly when using config variables in scripts.

So I want to simplify the access to these variables. I could use a dictionary, that is pre-populated when the class is loaded and do:

```
myLib.myClass.config['theItemIWant']
```

But I was thinking even a bit more elegantly. I wrote a separate Config class that I'd like to offer variable-level access to the config entries.

So what I want to be able to do is:

```
myLib.Config().theItemIWant
```

Or to instantiate an object in a script like this:

```
def myRoutine(self):
    cfg = myLib.Config()
    print cfg.theItemIWant
```

I've read about ugly (using exec) ways to accomplish this, and I'm actually OK with that, but I can't figure out how to set CLASS level variables this way. Most people suggest either using exec or altering either vars or globals, but I am not sure if this will accomplish setting the variables directly on the Config class and not somewhere else.

Using exec failed:

```
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function '__init__' it contains a nested function with free variables
```

So the only way I see to do it is to alter vars() but I'm not sure how this applies to classes.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, or why you would want to use `exec`, not least because you don't show a complete example. If you want to set a member variable, just set it.

Comment: Can you give an example of your code using `exec`?  It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  Why can't you just do `myLib.config.theItemIWant = whatever`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating dynamically named variables from user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354214/creating-dynamically-named-variables-from-user-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply implement the `__getattr__()` function for your configuration object like

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in self.items:
         return self.items[name]
    else:
         raise AttributeError()
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) for the description for `__getattr__()` in the python documentation.

Comment: It's spelled `__getattr__`

Comment: Or use the `setattr` operator.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that tries not to reinvent the wheel. Works when you want to only read config once, and its structure is flat.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def getConfig(config_source):
  # read the config_source into a dict
  # config_source might be a file name or whatnot
  config_dict = read_somehow(config_source)
  tuple_class = namedtuple('Config', config_dict.keys())
  return tuple_class(**config_dict)
```

The function returns an immutable object with attributes named after config parameter names.

```
  # suppose config file is something like:
  # a = 1 
  # foo = bar

  cfg = getConfig(...)
  print cfg.a # prints 1
  print cfg.foo # prints foo
  print cfg.unknown # raises AttributeError
```

I used to use this approach to read sections from standard `ConfigParser` instances.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just to assign to a member variable, like so:

```
class Foo(object):
      pass

cfg = Foo()
cfg.item_i_want = "An item"
print cfg.item_i_want
```

This will print "An item". See: http://ideone.com/LDz7NK

If you want to pick the variable name dynamically, use `setattr(cfg, "another_item_i_want", "another item")`.

Comment: This way you cannot set the attributes "dynamically" from your database entries ...