# Using variable to access another variable

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm not sure how to describe this or google it. What i want is to use a variable to access another variable. I'm guessing the answer will be using a dictionary of sorts.

```
personPaul = [1,2]
personJoe = [3,4]

def myFunc(name):
    return person + name

print myFunc("Paul")
print myFunc("Joe")
```

I want the output to be

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

Comment: Why even you want to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To convert string to variable name in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm guessing the answer will be using a dictionary of sorts

Exactly right :-)

```
people = {
    "Paul": [1,2],
    "Joe": [3,4]
}

def myFunc(name):
    return people[name]

print myFunc("Paul")
print myFunc("Joe")
```

Of course, you can also cut out the `myFunc` middleman and directly do `print people["Paul"]`.

Comment: Or a compromise:  `myFunc = people.get`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?:

```
people = {
    "Paul":[1,2],
    "Joe":[3,4]
}
print people["Paul"] # Gives you [1,2]
print people["Joe"] # Gives you [3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function to access to global variables inside the function and then use a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to loop over its items then check if your name is in a global name (the key) then print its corresponding value :

```
>>> personPaul = [1,2]
>>> personJoe = [3,4]
>>> def myFunc(name):
...     return next((v for k,v in globals().items() if name in k),None)
... 
>>> myFunc('Paul')
[1, 2]
>>> myFunc('jack')
>>>
```

Comment: One *can*, but one shouldn't. In any case, your iterator is just a long way of writing `globals().get(name, None)`.