# Python How to concat and retrieve actual defined data?

Tags: python

Ive been searching but I just cant find anything that describes my problem. Im just learning python so I might not even know how to properly phrase the question.

Im trying to randomize a selection of defined variables, but I can not figure out how to retrieve those variables. example:

```
import random

user1 = "usernamehere1"
userkey1 = "3097fds09aj4023jr30mf2ag2"
user2 = "usernamehere2"
userkey2 = "09asfh34907fsenk32498fgg9"
user3 = "usernamehere3"
userkey3 = "234kn34bnero8wn34lnkjwi34"

numbers =  ["1", "2", "3"]

user_number = random.choice(numbers)
user = "user" + user_number
wif = "userkey" + user_number

print(user)
print(wif)
```

Instead of getting: (say if it selects "2" as the random number):

- usernamehere2
- 09asfh34907fsenk32498fgg9

I just get:

- user2
- userkey2

Any guesses as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variables don't work like that. Use a dictionary.

Comment: You should be using a [dict](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Dictionaries) to store your users. That would allow you to access them as `my_dict["user" + user_number]`.

Comment: Thanks. Does that change how I randomize them?

Comment: Can anyone help with the actual code? Im lucky to even get it this far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this with just one dictionary:

```
import random

users = {
    "usernamehere1": "3097fds09aj4023jr30mf2ag2",
    "usernamehere2": "09asfh34907fsenk32498fgg9",
    "usernamehere3": "234kn34bnero8wn34lnkjwi34"
}

user = random.sample(users.keys(), 1)

print(user[0])
print(users[user[0]])
```

Comment: This works great! How do I assign user and wif?

For instance:

user = user[0]
wif = users[user[0]]

Comment: For this to work to assign variables:  

    `keypair = random.sample(users.keys(), 1)`  

    `user = keypair[0]`  
    `wif = users[keypair[0]]`  

    `print(user)`  
    `print(wif)`

Answer (score 1):

look at this post [To convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python), You can do what you want using exec to change strings to a variable, but this is not safe and definitely not recommended. As the post here explains you should use dictionaries instead to do this such as `users["user" + user_number]`

```
import random

user1 = "usernamehere1"
userkey1 = "3097fds09aj4023jr30mf2ag2"
user2 = "usernamehere2"
userkey2 = "09asfh34907fsenk32498fgg9"
user3 = "usernamehere3"
userkey3 = "234kn34bnero8wn34lnkjwi34"

dict = {}
dict[user1] = userkey1
dict[user2] = userkey2
dict[user3] = userkey3

numbers =  ["1", "2", "3"]

user_number = random.choice(numbers)
user = "user" + user_number

print(user)
print(dict[user])
```

Comment: Thanks. I am reading up on dictionaries now but it leads me to the same question. I dont understand if each keypair needs its own dictionary or how I would randomize them.

Comment: it depends how you want to store the information, you can either separate it out like other users have in their answers or do as I showed above where username is the key of the dictionary and the userkey is the value in the dictionary. It's a design choice

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct, I just wanted to share a way to implement them. You can think of dictionaries as "look up table" where you assign a key-->value pair. There is a lot of info [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

```
import random

users = {"1":"usernamehere1",
         "2":"usernamehere2",
         "3":"usernamehere3"}

keys = {"1":"3097fds09aj4023jr30mf2ag2",
        "2":"09asfh34907fsenk32498fgg9",
        "3":"234kn34bnero8wn34lnkjwi34"}

numbers =  ["1", "2", "3"]

user_number = random.choice(numbers)
user = "user" + users[user_number]
wif = "userkey" + keys[user_number]

print(user)
print(wif)
```

Comment: AWESOME! Im going to give this a shot. Im the type to learn with actual examples and I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Just wanted to say I was able to implement this for all 100 keypairs and it worked amazing.

Now Im re-reading everything in order to gain a basic understanding of dictionaries. Very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
users = [
        {
            'user':"usernamehere1",
            'userkey':"3097fds09aj4023jr30mf2ag2"
        },
        {
            'user':"usernamehere2",
            'userkey':"09asfh34907fsenk32498fgg9"
        },
        {
            'user':"usernamehere3",
            'userkey':"234kn34bnero8wn34lnkjwi34"
        }
    ]

user_number = random.choice(range(1,len(users)))

print(users[user_number]['user'])
print(users[user_number]['userkey'])
```