# How to convert a string to a variable name WITHOUT DICT

Tags: python

I need to convert a string to a variable name of a tuple and therefor ***i dont want to do it with a dictionary.*** I need to do it on python, I've searched already over the website and on many diffrent sources, and no answer satisfied me yet. I really hope for somthing simple as I hope this task is. Thanks alot to the helpers :)

Comment: do you need to be able to set the value of the variable?  or just retrieve it?

Comment: Local or global variable?

Comment: Do you have anything for us to go on?

Comment: already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python

Comment: local var, set value.

Comment: If you look at the questions linked as duplicate, there are ways that appear to do what you want, but if not, then you really need to edit the question to explain what you're trying to do and not just point out that you don't want to do it in a dictionary (especially since there's no explanation to your "therefor[e]"