# How to use input from the user to put as the name of a variable in python?

Tags: python, variables, peewee

I have a piece of code I'm trying to write. It is sort of like a lot of functions in one program. I'm giving it the form of a person. So I want to have different "accounts" in it that can change some things in it. This is what I have so far.

```
    from peewee import *
    import datetime
    from getpass import getpass

    db = SqliteDatabase("Butler_knows.db")

    class User(Model):
        name = TextField()
        password = TextField(), IntegerField()

        class Meta:
            database = db

    db.connect()

    New_not = raw_input("Do I know you? ")

    if New_not.strip().upper() == "NO":
        new_name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
        new_user = raw_input("What would you like me to call you? ")
        passwordcreate = getpass("What would you like your password to be?                ")
```

So what I want to know is, is there a way to use the input from "new_name" and use it as the variable for the dictionaries? This is using the peewee ORM. If you don't understand, this is what I mean.

```
    Randomname = User.create(name="Randomname", username="Randomname123",                     password="RandomPass")
```

That is how you create a user if you want to program a name you want. What should I do if I want to use the user's input as the name of the variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To convert string to variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name)

Comment: You can, but what will be the value?

Comment: i guess he thinking about string as dict name...

Comment: what he will put in values if what the user enters will be dictionary's keys?

Comment: `from peewee import *`  this is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to say is to use new_name as a key in the dictionary, which you can do as follows:

```
{new_name :[new_user, passwordcreate]}
```

but a better way could be:

```
{"name": new_name ,"user_name": new_user,"password": passwordcreate}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using user input as a variable name will only confuse you. 
How would you call the variable? 
It's better to make a variable 'name' and give it the value that the user specifies. I do think what you're looking for are tuples; key-value pairs. 
In Python, this is called a dictionary as has been laid out by yosemite_k.