# Create multiple lists of empty lists in one go

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following in a concise way:

```
n = 3
lst1 = [[] for _ in range(n)]
lst2 = [[] for _ in range(n)]
lst3 = [[] for _ in range(n)]
```

Basically generating a number of list of empty lists with the same size.

I am looking for a one-liner on this one. I tried using `zip` and various `itertools` but I must admit this set of features is one of my weak links with Python.

Comment: What is the expected outcome at the end? Are `lst1`, `lst2` different instances of list?

Comment: Yeah of course that's the whole point, creating different lists.

Comment: well, you could write a method which will return you these lists by passing `n`? Or, you could even store these lists in another list? It all depends on how many lists do you need.

Comment: @AKS yes? but I'm looking for a Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: How many such lists do you need?

Comment: Can't you use a list of lists of empty lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same with just one additional layer of list comprehension or generator expression and then unpacking it to variables:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> lst1, lst2, lst3 = ([[] for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(3))
>>> lst1
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: I don't think the OP has mentioned how many such lists are required? Does it really depend on `n`?

Comment: Ah I see what I missed now, I need to wrap my head around these generators, iters and such... But I think the last `range(n)` is wrong. It should be as many as the number of vars to unpack there are, so in this case `3`.

Comment: @AKS: He hasn't but in the question he has created 3 of them. Doesn't really depend on `n` or hasn't been stated, changed example accordingly.

Comment: @dabadaba: That is exactly what I was asking in the comments above. Exactly how many lists do you need? It pretty sure doesn't depend on `n` like you said.

Comment: @dabadaba: My bad, thought `n` had something to do with list size and the number of them, changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing the lists in different variables, I will suggest to wrap all the list within single list. Your code should be like:

```
>>> num_of_list, size_of_list = 5, 3
>>> my_list = [[[] for _ in range(size_of_list)] for _ in range(num_of_list)]
```

The value hold by `my_list` will be:

```
[
   [[], [], []], 
   [[], [], []], 
   [[], [], []], 
   [[], [], []], 
   [[], [], []]
]
```

For accessing each sub-list, you may simply use the index as:

```
>>> my_list[0]
[[], [], []]

>>> my_list[1]
[[], [], []]
```

If it is MUST to store the values in separate variables, you may unwrap the content of main list to individual variables as:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 = my_list
```

Comment: Not really. Even though here I named them `lst1`, `lst2`, etc... in practice they're going to be entirely separate (conceptually) ones, so it would not be a good idea to throw them in the same structure.

Comment: Updated the answer. I will suggest to initialize them as one variable say `raw_list` and then unwrap the values to variables for better clarity. My this comment is opinion based.

Comment: Why would I want a temporary useless variable when I what those concise variables I know I am going to use?

Comment: Why is the variable useless? It acts as a wrapper object to all the lists you initialized together at the first place. By not declaring this variable are you saving your memory space? The answer is NO. Remaining sub-list variables will still point to existing objects. This is the pattern I follow and have seen advantages of it with time. As I mentioned, I **suggest** that. To follow or not is your wish :)

Comment: Relax, I am just trying to understand your point of view, I think you took it way too bad. And well, sorry but I still don't see your point. And I never implied that would save memory, what I meant is that it seems a meaningless variable. Say that you want to have lists of `teams`, `scores` and `dates`. That's what you want. Not a `raw_list` with 3 sublists. What are you even going to do with `raw_list`? In this case, it serves no purpose, so why not just do what the other answer suggested?

Answer (score -1):

```
n = 3
for i in range(1, n+1):
    exec("lst%s = [[] for _ in range(%s)]" % (i, n))
```

Based on [To convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name)