# When uploading a whole folder of files, how can I assign them all relevant variable names?

Tags: python

Let's say I'm uploading

```
Desktop/folder/dog.jpg, Desktop/folder/fish.jpg, Desktop/folder/lizard.jpg
```

Could I theoretically do something like

```
a = ['Desktop/folder/dog.jpg', 'Desktop/folder/fish.jpg', 'Desktop/folder/lizard.jpg']

for x in a
    b = read(x)
    regex(x)= b
```

so that without doing each one manually, it ends up like

```
dog=read(dog.jpg)
fish=read(fish.jpg)
lizard=read(lizard.jpg)
```

?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, particularly where your pseudocode assigns something to a function call.

Comment: You can refer the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name which is similar to what you want

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that extracts a name from a filename:

```
def getname(astr):
    import os.path
    name = os.path.basename(astr)
    name = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
    return name
```

From your list of filenames I can get a list of 'variable' names:

```
In [150]: filenames = ['Desktop/folder/dog.jpg', 'Desktop/folder/fish.jpg', 'Desktop/folder/lizard.jpg'] 
In [155]: [getname(i) for i in filenames]
Out[155]: ['dog', 'fish', 'lizard']
```

But rather than try to put them in the global name space, I'd suggest collecting them in a dictionary:

```
In [156]: adict = {getname(i): i for i in filenames}
In [157]: adict
Out[157]: 
{'dog': 'Desktop/folder/dog.jpg',
 'fish': 'Desktop/folder/fish.jpg',
 'lizard': 'Desktop/folder/lizard.jpg'}
```

Or if with a `read` function:

```
adict = {getname(i): read(i) for i in filenames}
```

Generally in Python it is more useful to collect objects, like these images, in a list or dictionary, rather than trying to assign each one to a separate variable.

It's nearly as easy to write `adict['fish']` as it is `fish`. With the dictionary you can easily 'loop' over the whole set

```
for k,v in adict.items():
   print('name:',k)
   display(v)
```

A comment links to a whole string of SO questions about assigning to variables, and why generally that is a poor idea.