# Why is 'exec()' considered worse than 'setattr()' when it comes to dynamically setting local variables

Tags: python, variables

I have searched methods of dynamically setting local variables on the Stack Overflow and saw many suggested using `setattr` and didn't recommend `exec()` (`dict()` or `vars()` were also suggested, but the first two seem pythonic to me).

But no one tells why `exec()` is worse or unsafe.

Could somebody explain this?

Comment: How do you use `setattr` to set a local variable?

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. `setattr` is used to set **_object attributes_**, not local variables. `exec` is used to dynamically execute Python code. As for why `exec` is general considered unsafe, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

Comment: It looks like OP is trying to have a workaround by creating an empty class Creating an object of the same ,then use setattr to set/create new attributes to that local object

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable and referred the question title as I didn't know exact concept applied here.

Comment: Also note that dynamically creating variables is very, _very_ rarely a good idea nor necessary. Use a data structure such as a list or dictionary.

Comment: @ChristianDean thanks for the advice. I also figured out that I can simply use a dictionary, but I am still curious why `exec()` is unsafe as many warned.

Comment: Maybe my question is more about why `exec()` is unsafe as you suggested. Thanks @ChristianDean

Comment: If you're sure about that, then I'll mark this duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ !