# Python - assign variable names as elements of array dynamically

Tags: python

I have a list which includes some values such as

```
tableVal = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

I want to use each element as a variable and, assign correspondingly as parameter of a function such as:

```
for i in tableVal:
    i = myFunc(print "this is your value: "+ i)
```

So when I type `>> val1`, it should return `this is your value: val1`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you feel that using a dict to do something similar won't work?

Comment: Please indent code by 4 spaces instead of using ``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name)

Comment: Do you want 'val1' to become a function (so `val1()` returns or print something), a variable (like `val1 = "this is you value: val1"`), or do you want to print more text when typing 'val1' in the console (without really modifying val1) ?

Comment: `globals().update(dict((i, 'this is your value: {}'.format(i)) for i in tableVal))`?

Comment: @Goyo, with slight modification for the real problem context it solved. Thanks, can you update as reply so I can accept?. And it is surprising four minus voting just because of duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, the proper way of mapping names to values dynamically is using a dictionary:

```
d = dict((i, 'this is your value: {}'.format(i)) for i in tableVal)
print d['val1']
```

Output:

```
this is your value: val1
```

You can add this mapping to `globals()` so your names become global variables:

```
globals().update(d)
print val1
```

Output:

```
this is your value: val1
```

But this is almost always a bad idea. Other people will not expect variables being magically created and they might shadow pre-existing variables. You can mitigate the risk by putting them in their own namespace:

```
class Namespace(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        vars(self).update(d)

n = Namespace(d)
print n.val1
```

This allow you to use autocomplete in an IDE or the IPython shell without polluting your global namespace.

An even better alternative using the standard library, if immutability is OK, is `collections.namedtuple`:

```
n = namedtuple('Namespace', tableVal)(*d.values())
print n.val1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function with a dictionary:

```
tableVal = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
new_table = {i:(lambda x: lambda :"this is your value: {}".format(x))(i) for i in tableVal}
new_table['val2']()
```

Output:

```
this is your value: val2
```