# How do I turn a string into a variable name

Tags: python

How can I turn a string, say 'a' into a variable name on which I can use the append function?

I am trying to take the input, which is made ut of only small letters of the alphabet and record the posision of the letter in the string with a number under a variable of the letters name. The problem i have encountered is that I have to turn the string that i have from the input into a variable name that i can use the append funtion on.
I have tried using vars() after I saw it somewhere (don't really know what vars() does since I'm new to this). This worked fine sometimes, but not always.
Now I'm looking for a better way to do it.

```
'''This is the code i have now. This does not work all the time'''
ord = input()
count = 1
for i in ord:
    i = vars()[i]
    i.append(count)
    count = count + 1
    i = []
```

Comment: You don't! The better way to do it is to use a dictionary. Messing with local variables will bite you back at some point.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your motivation is very vague. Can you describe what your ultimate goal is rather than how you tried to go about accomplishing it? (It sounds a bit like you want to count how many times a word has occurred in the input.)

Comment: @freakish i can't because i may have more than two of one value.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here, what does the number under a letter represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proper solution corresponding to what you are trying to do (which is letter indexing I think) using dictionaries:

```
result = {}
ord = input()  # why do you call that variable ord?
count = 1
for i in ord:
    if i not in result:
        result[i] = []
    result[i].append(count)
    count += 1
print(result)
```

No vars, no locals, no **messing** with an unsafe context. No problem when someone types `i` in your input and similar other issues. Everything safe and simple. It can be further simplified by the usage of [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

As a side note: forget about the existence of vars/locals/globals and similar objects. I've never had to use them even though I've been programming in Python for a decade. These are interesting when you write some crazy code like a Python debugger. Otherwise not needed. And these are swords that will cut you unless you're a samurai.

Comment: Also only ever used `locals` et al once and agree that they should only ever be considered when fully understand how scope affects an application

Answer (score 0):

You just need a dictionary that adds the indexes to a list, defaultdict is great for this

```
from collections import defaultdict
text = input()
result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, letter in enumerate(text):
     result[letter].append(idx)

print(result)
```

output for the string `asdc` would be `{'a': [0], 'c': [3], 's': [1], 'd': [2]}`

Answer (score -1):

The `vars()` function returns a dictionary of all variables defined in the current context. You can use it to set values or append new values to lists. Check on the script bellow for an example:

```
data=[]
print("Field Name:")
field=input()
print("Value:")
ord1 = input()
print("VALUE: {}".format(field))
i = vars().get(field,None)
if i is not None:
    i.append(ord1)
print(data)
```

You can add values to this map using

```
vars()['key']='Value'
```

Result:

```
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'key': 'Value', '__package__': None}
```