# printing multiple variables with numbered names in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

How can I print multiple variables that are named for example var0, var1, var2, var3, etc, using a for loop

```
#these are my variables
var0 = 'empty'
var1 = 'something'
var2 = 'something again'
var3 = 'last thing'

for x in range(0,4):
    print(varX)
```

I want the varX expression to be able to print each variable at a time.

Comment: I think you should consider `dictionary` object. [(intro)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name)

Comment: The problem is, I must use variable strings.

Comment: there is *no good reason* to use numbered variables here. use a proper container like a list or a dict.

Comment: Why *must* you use strings? Is this a homework assignment? It would be nice if you explain the reason here, because using strings > variable names is really not a pythonic way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use numbered variable names in the first place; use a list.

```
vars = ['empty', 'something', 'something again', 'last thing']

for var in vars:
    print(var)
```

Comment: I wish it would've been easier. I am working with a NLP library and I must use separated variables.

Comment: @YassineLachgar I think you must be misunderstanding something. If the library requires strings, then the library is **not** taking variables, it's simply taking strings. I'd be absolutely shocked to see that some library is invoking an `eval` against the arguments you pass to it.  If you can revise your question with [MCVE] that illustrates the *actual problem* you're facing there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
#these are my variables
var0 = 'empty'
var1 = 'something'
var2 = 'something again'
var3 = 'last thing'

for x in range(0,4):
    print(eval("var" + str(x)))
```

more examples on `eval()` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval). What `eval()` does is execute python code within itself ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do))

Answer (score 0):

as already said it's better to use array or dictionary. However you can achieve this via `globals()` function

```py
for x in range(0, 4):
    print(globals()['var' + x])
```

Comment: You are assuming the variables are globals.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary as follows:

```
d = dict()
d['var0'] = 'empty'
d['var1'] = 'something'
d['var2'] = 'something again'
d['var3'] = 'last thing'
for x in range(0,4):
    print(d["var"+str(x)])
```