# Using for list to assign variable names

Tags: python, pandas

Bit of a simple question. I would like to iterate through 2 lists, the first to name the variable and the second to read a csv. I want to assign the csv to the variable based on the name my list is iterating through.

Here is a sample of the code I have written:

```
lists = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight']
for i in lists:
    for j in range(1,9):
        i = merger(path,path_2,j)
```

In this case I am not assigning the items in lists to the variable i (as the variable name)

The function merge merely takes two paths, reads the csvs from each and merges them using pd.concat

Comment: Not really possible in `python`. Use a dictionary like: `csv_dict = {}` and then in the loop: `csv_dict[i] = merger(path,path_2,j)`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name). However, `exec` isn't always very efficient.

You should consider using a dictionary with the names as keys instead.

```py
lists = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight']
csv = {}
for i in lists:
    for j in range(1,9):
        csv[i] = merger(path, path_2, j)
```