# iterate over files in directory and use file names as variables, and assign the file path to the variable

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, directory-structure, azure-databricks

I was trying to iterate through a folder and get the names of files and paths of these files in DataBricks using Pyspark.
And suddenly a thought came like if we could make the names of files as variable and assign the path to that respective file named variable.
We could use dbutils to create widgets and assign the file name as parameter, to make things easier.
So working on this process I came till obtaining the paths of files and filenames.
But I couldn't figure out the variable creation and assigning the paths of the respective files in the respective file name variables
Here's the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import os
list1 =[]
list2 =[]
directory='/dbfs/FileStore/tables'
dir='/FileStore/tables'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  if filename.endswith(".csv") or filename.endswith(".txt"):
    file_path=os.path.join(dir, filename)
    print(file_path)
    print(filename)
    list1.append(file_path)
    list2.append(filename)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name. But the real question is why not use a dictionary instead with `filename` as key and `file_path` as value?

Comment: let's suppose I have 100 files in a folder and I just want to create a DataFrame  for a single  file, If I get to  create variables in a dictionary, I must have to remember the keys in the dictionary, and if I get to have the variables with the file name and the file paths assigned to it, I could just pass the variable name and create the whole data frame with little effort

Comment: not sure what you mean by ..."remember the keys in the dictionary...", but assigning variables would also require memory overhead, more I think. A dictionary is the best data structure for this type of operation - it's compact, portable, and efficient .

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion, I will check on both results and update here, about the pros and cons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're set on assigning paths to variables with the file name, then you can try:

```
...
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  if filename.endswith(".csv") or filename.endswith(".txt"):
    file_path=os.path.join(dir, filename)
    print(file_path)
    print(filename)
    exec("%s = '%s'" % (filename, file_path))
```

Notice the additional set of quotes avoid syntax and name errors. However, this solution is still fraught with problems. For example, it looks like the call to `exec` takes the backslashes in a file path as unicode:

```
filename = 'file1'
filepath = '\maindir\foo'
exec("%s = '%s'" % (filename, filepath))
file1
'\\maindir\x0coo'
```

But a dictionary seems much better suited to his situation:

```
...
filenames_and_paths = {}
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  if filename.endswith(".csv") or filename.endswith(".txt"):
    file_path=os.path.join(dir, filename)
    print(file_path)
    print(filename)
    filenames_and_paths[filename] = file_path
```

Not sure why you've created the two lists for the names and paths, but if they are needed you can also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
filenames_and_paths = {name:path for name,path in zip(list1, list2)}
```

Comment: 12
      exec("%s = %s" % (filename, file_path))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<command-2865892692314831>", line 12, in <module>
    exec("%s = %s" % (filename, file_path))

  File "<string>", line 1
    Dept_data.csv = /FileStore/tables/Dept_data.csv
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @younus, try adding an additional set of quotes. I've edited answer to include this, but I've also played around with this and have run into issues with backslashes being interpreted as unicode. There's no reason to implement what you're trying to do this way. A dictionary is the simply better.

Answer (score 0):

With Pyspark I'd rather suggest using the Hadoop FS API to list files as `os.listdir` won't work with external buckets/storage.

Here is an example that you can adapt:

```
# access hadoop fs via the JVM
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

# list directory
directory = Path("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/*.csv")
gs = directory.getFileSystem(conf).globStatus(directory)

# create tuples (filename, filepath), you can also filter specific files here...
paths = []
if gs:
    paths = [(f.getPath().getName(), f.getPath().toString()) for f in gs]

for filename, file_path in paths:
    # your process
```