# python return a list from a function to another function as input list

Tags: python

I am trying to return a function but as list NAME, in another function should accept a list but it seems it return string into the second function

```
choices = ['a', 'b','c']
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']
choices = tuple(choices)
def let_user_pick(choices):
    print("Please choose:")
    for idx, element in enumerate(choices):
        print("{}) {}".format(idx+1,element))
    i = int(input("Enter number: "))

    if 0 < int(i) <= len(choices):
        return choices[i-1]

def a2_only(data):
    print(data)

a2_only(let_user_pick(choices))
```

so I need to run the second function as below (logically calling a list not string)

```
a2_only(c) NOT a2_only('c')
```

Current ouput:

```
Please choose:
1) a
2) b
3) c
Enter number: 3
c
```

expected ouput:

```
['7','8','9']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to variable name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use globals to access dict of the current variables scope. Something like this

```
choices = ['a', 'b','c']
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']
choices = tuple(choices)
def let_user_pick(choices):
    print("Please choose:")
    for idx, element in enumerate(choices):
        print("{}) {}".format(idx+1,element))
    i = int(input("Enter number: "))

    if 0 < int(i) <= len(choices):
        c = choices[i-1]
        return globals().get(c)

def a2_only(data):
    print(data)

a2_only(let_user_pick(choices))
```

Comment: thanks a lot that works
I changed a bit in the code and still working fine
return  globals().get(choices[i-1])

Comment: Usage of `globals` is however very bad in any programming language, see this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Answer (score 2):

You could change the first few lines to be

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']
choices = [a, b, c]
```

That way you are putting the lists in the list instead of the names of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There already is an excellent answer by @JuanPotato; however, you could also use a python `dict` here:

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']
choices = {'a': a, 'b': b,'c': c}
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def let_user_pick(choices):
    print("Please choose:")
    for idx, element in enumerate(keys):
        print("{}) {}".format(idx+1,element))
    i = int(input("Enter number: "))

    if 0 < int(i) <= len(choices.keys()):
        return choices.get(keys[i-1])

def a2_only(data):
    print(data)

a2_only(let_user_pick(choices))

# Please choose:
# 1) a
# 2) b
# 3) c
# Enter number: 3
# c
# ['7', '8', '9']
```

If the order is important, have a look at pythons `OrderedDict`.

Here is a repl.it if you want to test it yourself: https://repl.it/repls/CylindricalDecentDriverwrapper

Comment: the idea that i have to update choices manually each time based on lists given, but whatever lists i have i run for loop append to choices and second function will run without any intervention
imagine now i have a,b,c lists after an hour i have a,b,d,f

Comment: @thesmall You could as well create your `choices` dict from any given key value pair. It is not enough to simply extend the `choices` list without any values attached to them, right? You can as well write your own function to recreate the `choices` dict from the keys and the values. However, I'd suggest using a python dict right away to have the correct choice to value mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess. You are hiding the actual end output from the user. When they see `1) a` and they press 1, why would they expect the return to be ['1', '2', '3']?

Also, what is the point of the `a2_only()` function if it's just a limited form of the built-in print() function?

I would rewrite the code as the following, which I think makes more sense:

```
def let_user_pick(choices):
    print("Please choose:")
    for _ in choices:
        print("{}) {}".format(_, choices[_]))

    choice = input("Enter choice: ")

    try:
        return choices[choice]
    except KeyError:
        return "Invalid option!"


options = {
    'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'b': ['4', '5', '6'],
    'c': ['7', '8', '9']
}

print(let_user_pick(options))
```

BTW: I know this technically isn't what you are looking for. [Anton Pomieshchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61605900/) has already provided a direct answer to your question. You can also see [this answer by StefanW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19122532) that shows how you can change variables as strings through the `exec()` function. However, that is highly frowned upon and considered to be bad coding style.

Comment: thanks, this is not the full code, it is an example for simplicity, but a,b,c have other related names