# Convert all columns in a Pandas DF to separate lists and assign it a name same as column name

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to create separate lists for each column in a pandas DF and this code doesn't seem to work and not sure why:

```
columns = df.columns
for column in columns:
    column = list(df[column])
```

So, if I have a column `df['LAT']`, I need a series name *LAT* with `df['LAT']` as values. I am not able to find a way to loop over all the columns to do this but when I select individuals columns it works, like:

```
LAT = list(df['LAT'])
```

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19122532/4819376) but I think it will be better use dictionary as inthis [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19122387/4819376)

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier (and probably better) to create a dictionary where each key is the name of the column and each value is a Series:

```py
columns = df.columns
columns_dict = {} # empty dictionary

for column_name in columns:
    # assign column to dictionary key
    columns_dict[column_name] = df[column_name].tolist()
```

Then the list for *LAT* would be accessible as `columns_dict["LAT"]`.

Comment: This is exactly the suggestion in my comment.