# Assign values of a nested dictionary to variables named after the keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to assign the values of a nested dictionary to variables named after their key. I found this code on Stackoverflow but it only prints the key and value pair:

```
def myprint(d):
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        myprint(v)
    else:
        print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
```

I would like it so that for example, if I have the following in my dictionary: `{thisIsADummy : 37}`

I can somehow create a variable named `thisIsADummy`, named after the key, with the value `37`
So my input ould be `print(thisIsADummy)` and the output would be `37`

Please let me know if anybody has any ideas on how to do this as efficiently as possible, because this dictionary has probably over a thousand pairs. Thank you.

EDIT:
Using `exec` works well, but I oversimplified in the original post. I need the variable to be a dictionary so when I open multiple files I can append values.

Comment: YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS: Having said that, this should work `globals().update(dictionary)` as `globals()` is just a dict and you can update it just like a dict

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't understand what this does.

Comment: I think exec is what I was thinking of, not eval [Convert string to variable name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python). It's also a bad idea `exec("x = 3")`

Comment: @MatthewKaplan `globals()` is a dict like object that contains all of your current global variables. This globals object is mutable so instead of doing `a = 1` you could do `globals()['a'] = 1`. I highly recommend against doing this though as it will make your code hard to reason about and likely run into weird and unexpected issues

Comment: `{thisIsADummy : 37}`, should it be `{"thisIsADummy" : 37}`?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `eval()`,Try `setattr`(I am not sure whether it is a better way.):

```
import sys

d = {"thisIsADummy": 37, 'a': [123,2]}
for k, v in d.items():
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], k, v)

a.append(1)
print(thisIsADummy, a)
```

Result:

```
37 [123, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I oversimplified my original post because I didn't think it would matter much, but I'm actually going to be opening multiple files so it would help if the variable was a list so I could append values. Do you have any ideas how best to accomplish this?

Comment: @MatthewKaplan It would be okay if your value is a list.

Comment: How would I append values? The original variable is an int.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is to use 'exec' function like below.

```
nat = {
    'abc': 1,
    'a123': 2,
    'a1b': 3,
    'b31': 4
}

for k, v in nat.items():
    exec("%s = %d" % (k, v))
    print(k, v)

print(abc, a123, a1b, b31)
```

Note: It will only work if keys follows the variable name constraints

Comment: Stupid Jupyter Notebook had the variable stored. `for k, v in t.items(): exec(f'{k} = v')`

Comment: @GauravVijayvargia thanks for the suggestion. It actually works and saves it in a variable which is great. Unfortunately, I oversimplified my original post because I didn't think it would matter much, but I'm actually going to be opening multiple files so it would help if the variable was a list so I could append values. Do you have any ideas how best to accomplish this?

Comment: @MatthewKaplan If I understand your problem correctly then this will help 'exec("%s = [%d]" % (k, v))'. It will create key strings as list variable

Comment: @GauravVijayvargia unfortunately this will not work for me because the value is not always an int %d only accepts ints. Is there a way to change this so it accepts all types? I was actually just using `exec('k=v')` before which worked for me. If I was only using ints this would work perfectly.

Comment: @MatthewKaplan try  'exec("%s = ['%s']" % (k, v))'.

Comment: @MatthewKaplan if you want to use the exact type, then you might have to use if else conditions on types