# Use string to create variable name and its value in Python

Tags: python, django, string

I have One String in python

```
field_name = "status"
value = "joined"
```

I want to convert this string to some variable name like,

```
status = "joined"
```

my Indention is Django ORM

```
model.objects.filter(status = 'joined')
```

Any Suggestion doing for this..

Here am reffered this URL [Convert string to variable name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python)

but here it happend only integer.
not working string type of values
any one help me

Comment: Don't do this, it isn't necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for Django ORM you can pass parameters as a dictionary:

```
field_name = "status"
value = "joined"

filter_params = {
    field_name: value
}

model.objects.filter(**filter_params)
```

or just:

```
field_name = "status"
value = "joined"

model.objects.filter(**{field_name: value})
```

See [this page](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-unpack-list-tuple-or-dictionary-to-function-arguments-using/) for more details on unpacking a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
field_name = "status" 
value = "joined"

exec(f'{field_name} = "{value}"')
```

Comment: `exec` could be very unsafe. There is a better way by using dict unpacking

Comment: `locals()[field_name] = value` will create the variable without issues

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev agree, but that's one solution