# loop through variables names in Python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, variables, slice

I am working in Python.
I have a dataframe called df with 3 columns: a, b, c.
I want to do a loop which loops through all variables and generates a numpy array for each variable and cuts the last number of each variable. So far I have tried, but it is not working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    variables= [a,b,c]
    for x in variables:
        x  = np.transpose(np.matrix(df.x.to_numpy(np.float64)))
        x=x[:-1]
```

Comment: How about simply `for col in df.columns: ... df[col]...`?

Comment: Note that you are reassigning your loop variable `x`, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I do want to generate 3 variables called a,b and c. This is probably not optimal but I have the rest of the code generated like this...

Comment: `df.to_numpy()` produces a 2d array, `df.x` is series, and result is 1d.  Why `np.matrix` and `transpose`?  If you want to assign the the elements of some array to 3 variables use `unpacking`, `a,b,c = np.array([1,2,3])`.

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> I do want to generate 3 variables called a,b and c. This is probably not optimal but I have the rest of the code generated like this

It sounds like what you're really asking here is how to dynamically set a variable name to match an arbitrary character string.

If you reeeeallly want to do that, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python) and its chain of duplicates will give you some options.

But I would strongly STRONGLY encourage you to look for other ways of doing this. A dict is the most obvious option. If the rest of your code requires it, you're probably best off fixing up the rest of your code.