# TypeError: string indices must be integers in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

Why this code gives me typeError? And how can I call a dictionary using varible X?
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"
I print "espresso" in input.
Thanks

```
machine = {"Water": 300, "Milk": 200, "Coffe": 100,}
espresso = {"Water": 50, "Milk": 0, "Coffe": 28,}


def check(x):
   
    z = machine["Water"] >= x["Water"]
    print(z)

x = input()
check(x)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `check` ? Please explain.

Comment: it is checking if machine have enough water for input = espresso

Comment: And what are the possible values of `x`?

Comment: different types of coffe. In this case i have only ecspresso in dictionary. So X could be different input "espresso', "latte" and etc.

Comment: I dont see any 'latte' in the post.

Comment: ``machine`` and ``espresso`` should themselves be key/value pairs in yet another, outer dictionary.

Comment: latte and other types of coffe will appera later. And Machine dictionary represent the resotces machine has to make coffe. Espresso dictionary represented the requirments to produce coffe. So they cant be key and value for one dictionary

Answer (score 0):

use dictionary for mapping. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python)

```
machine = {"Water": 300, "Milk": 200, "Coffe": 100,}
espresso = {"Water": 50, "Milk": 0, "Coffe": 28,}


def check(x):
    d ={'espresso':espresso} 
    z = machine["Water"] >= d[x]["Water"]
    print(z)

x = input()
check(x)
```

Comment: yes. Could you please check again my message. I have edit it. The problem that I am calling to dictionary through function with input.

Answer (score -1):

because x holds:
x = "espresso"
and it is not a dictionary as you call it...
you can't ask x["Water"].

you need to change from:
x = "espresso"
to
x = espresso

Comment: yes. Could you please check again my message. I have edit it. The problem that I am calling to dictionary through function with input.