# How do I add Gurobi constraints and variables from lists of strings in an automated way?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, constraints, gurobi

**Objective:**
Add variables and constraints in a loop to a Gurobi model from a list of variables and a list of constraints each of varying lengths where each variable and constraint is stored as a string

**Problem:**
Gurobi only accepts variables and constraints in the Gurobi linear expression type.
I need to do this in an automated way because the list of constraints might be very long. So somehow I need to convert those strings to a Gurobi LinExpr type.

**Data:**
I have a list of variables as in this example:

```
variables=["y1","y2","y3","y4","y5","y6","y7"]
```

and I have a list of constraints like that:

```
['y6+y7-d*y1>=0', '1*y2+1*y3-1*u1*d-y6-y7+d*y1>=0', '1*y4+1*y5-u2*1*d-y6-y7+d*y1>=0', '1*x1+1*x2-1*d-1*y2-1*y3+1*u1*d-1*y4-1*y5+u2*1*d+y6+y7-d*y1>=0']
```

**Desired Solution:**

I want to add those variables to my Gurobi model as in this example:

```
y1 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y1", lb=0)
y2 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y2", lb=0)
y3 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y3", lb=0)
y4 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y4", lb=0)
y5 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y5", lb=0)
y6 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y6", lb=0)
y7 = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y7", lb=0)
```

and the constraints like that:

```
c1 = model.addConstr(y1+y2-d*y1>=0,"c1")
c2 = model.addConstr(1*y2+1*y3-1*y5*d-y6-y7+d*y1>=0,"c2")
c3 = model.addConstr(1*y4+1*y5-u2*1*d-y6-y7+d*y1>=0,"c3")
c4 = model.addConstr(1*y1+1*y2-1*d-1*y2-1*y3+1*u1*d-1*y4-1*y5+u2*1*d+y6+y7-d*y1>=0,"c4")
```

**My Try:**

I tried to store the data in a dictionary and use the update  function to store the variables and constraints like this:

```
y_dict={}
for y_variable in range(y_count-1):
        y_dict['y{}'.format(y_variable+1)]=model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "y{}".format(y_variable+1), lb=0)
locals().update(c_dict)

c_dict={}
for idx, constraint in enumerate(list_of_constraints):
    c_dict['c{}'.format(idx+1)]=model.addConstr(eval(constraint),"c{}".format(idx+1))
locals().update(c_dict)
```

But, the error I get when I set the objective is

```
GurobiError: Variable not in model
```

Is there any way to convert strings to the Gurobi Linear Expression type?

Comment: Can you provide a full **reproducible** example that shows how you try to set the objective? In the meantime, make sure that all other variables `u1, u2, x1, x2` etc are defined. Modifying the logical symbol table is a bit hacky, but should work. And I think it should be `locals().update(y_dict)` after your first loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This actually helped me. Because when trying to reproduce the error with a minimum example the error stopped to occur. I am still working on finding out where the original error came from.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise answer to your question but please keep in mind that this is very unsafe and error-prone and should never be used in actual code:

```py
import gurobipy as gp

m = gp.Model()
variables = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5", "y6", "y7"]
constraints = ["y1+3*y2-y3>=2", "y4+y5+y6+y7==2"]

for v in variables:
    exec(f"{v} = m.addVar(name = '{v}')")

for c in constraints:
    exec(f"m.addConstr({c})")

m.write("out.lp")
```

`out.lp:`

```
Minimize
 
Subject To
 R0: y1 + 3 y2 - y3 >= 2
 R1: y4 + y5 + y6 + y7 = 2
Bounds
End
```

Similar questions have been asked multiple times on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python) and in the linked duplicates) and the best way to work with "strings as variable names" simply is a dictionary.

Using [addVars()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addvars.html) is the correct way of creating the set of variables according to your specified list of names:

```py
v = m.addVars(variables)
m.update()
print(v)
```

`output`:

```
{'y1': <gurobi.Var C0>, 'y2': <gurobi.Var C1>, 'y3': <gurobi.Var C2>, 
 'y4': <gurobi.Var C3>, 'y5': <gurobi.Var C4>, 'y6': <gurobi.Var C5>,
 'y7': <gurobi.Var C6>
}
```

This is not possible for the list constraints, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, another approach worth mentioning would be to transform all variables inside the constraint strings into index notation, e.g. `y1` becomes `y[1]`. Using regular expressions, this is straightforward:

```py
import re

def clean_constr_str(s, var_names):
    for var_name in var_names:
        s = re.sub(r"(" + var_name + r")(\d*)", r"\1[\2]", s)
    return s
```

Here, `s` is the constraint string and `var_names` is an iterable containing all variable names. Given that you already know the variable names, this allows you to add all variables at once as a tupledict and then parse the constraints without modifying the logical symbol table:

```py
import gurobipy as gp

variables = ["y1","y2","y3","y4","y5","y6","y7"]

list_of_constraints = [
    'y6+y7-d*y1>=0', 
    '1*y2+1*y3-1*u1*d-y6-y7+d*y1>=0', 
    '1*y4+1*y5-u2*1*d-y6-y7+d*y1>=0', 
    '1*x1+1*x2-1*d-1*y2-1*y3+1*u1*d-1*y4-1*y5+u2*1*d+y6+y7-d*y1>=0'
]

model = gp.Model()

# Add all variables
y = model.addVars(range(1, len(variables)+1), vtype="C", name="y")
d = model.addVar(vtype="C", name="d")
u = model.addVars(range(1, 3), vtype="C", name="u")
x = model.addVars(range(1, 3), vtype="C", name="x")

# add the constraints
c = {}
for i, constraint in enumerate(list_of_constraints, 1):
    con = eval(clean_constr_str(constraint, ["y", "u", "x"]))
    c[i] = model.addConstr(con, name=f"c{i}")

model.update()
print(model.display())
```

yields

```
Minimize
  <gurobi.LinExpr: 0.0>
Subject To
  c1: <gurobi.QuadExpr: y[6] + y[7] + [ -1.0 y[1] * d ]> >= 0
c2: <gurobi.QuadExpr: y[2] + y[3] + -1.0 y[6] + -1.0 y[7] + [ y[1] * d + -1.0 d * u[1]
 ]> >= 0
c3: <gurobi.QuadExpr: y[4] + y[5] + -1.0 y[6] + -1.0 y[7] + [ y[1] * d + -1.0 d * u[2]
 ]> >= 0
c4: <gurobi.QuadExpr: -1.0 y[2] + -1.0 y[3] + -1.0 y[4] + -1.0 y[5] + y[6] + y[7] +
 -1.0 d + x[1] + x[2] + [ -1.0 y[1] * d + d * u[1] + d * u[2] ]> >= 0
```