# Prepopulating instances in code for classes (Python)

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make it so that when I can run a function which would populate a class with a couple of instances which are contained within the code.

```
class Pets(object):

  def __init__(self, name, scientific_name, feet_number, type)
    super(Pets,self).__init__()
    self.name = name
    self.scientific_name = scientific_name
    self.feet_number = feet_number
    self.type = type
```

This is the point where I get stuck. 
I want to make a function which has a list of instances (Ex. a dog, a cat, a horse...) so that when the function is run those instances can be accessed immediately.

I know from places like [Creating dynamically named variables from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354214/creating-dynamically-named-variables-from-user-input) (Second Paragraph, First Sentence), that what I'm asking for is possible, I just don't know the syntax for it.

Comment: Why are you calling `super(Pets, self)`? What constructor do you intend this to run?

Comment: This is a very confusing question.  You can run code like `my_instance = Pets('bob', robert, 2, my_type)` from a function which will create an instance with those values.  Do you mean something else?

Comment: I was just taught to use always use super in classes in case I need to create inheritance later.

Comment: @joel goldstick, I want to make a function which as a list of instances (Ex. a dog, a cat, a horse...) so that when the function is run those instances can already be accessed

Comment: So where do you want to instantiate those instances?

Comment: I was thinking of putting it in a function at the beginning of script that I would just call the first time it was run.

Comment: You only need `super` if you're already inheriting from another class (`object` is different) *and* you want to run its `__init__()` function, too.

Comment: @MattDMo You also need `super` if you intend for other classes to inherit *from* your class in a cooperative inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: You don't populate a class with instances of itself. A class defines a type; it is not a container.

Comment: @chepner ah, I did not know that. TIL :)

Comment: @joelgoldstick, but how would I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
class Pet(object):
  def __init__(self, details):
    self.name = details[0]
    self.scientific_name = details[1]
    self.feet_number = details[2]
    self.type = details[3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pet_list = [('Cat', 'Kitty Cat', 4, 'Cuddly'), ('Dog', 'Puppy Wuppy', 3, 'Licky')]
    pets = [Pet(item) for item in pet_list]
```

Which gives you:

```
pets
> [<__main__.Pet at 0x8134d30>, <__main__.Pet at 0x8134d68>]

pets[0]
> <__main__.Pet at 0x8134d30>

pets[0].name
> 'Cat'

pets[0].scientific_name
> 'Kitty Cat'

pets[1].name
> 'Dog'
```

There are a lot of ways this could be put together depending on what you want to do.  For example, you could make a master class called `Pet()` with some basic attributes and methods that are true for all pets, then create specific classes for each pet that inherit the base class, e.g. `class Cat(Pet):`

Or you could give the `Pet` class the ability to know all the other details depending on what `name` is passed into it, then populate the instance variables accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for, I just needed to change the way I wanted to structure my code slightly. Again thank you.