# how to create a new dictionary using for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

suppose I have lists of strings like this

```
list1 = ["x","y","z"]
```

so how can create empty dictionaries like `x = {}`, `y = {}` and `z = {}` by iteration

Following method does nothing:

```
for i in list1:
    i = dict()
```

Comment: There is a debate in the answer : do you want new variables, like `print(x) # {}` or indexes to access the dict `print(somename['x']) # {}` ?

Comment: Could you answer us ? Because some answers are upvoted, one is accepted, and all of them gives different answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is one solution :

```
for i in list1:
    locals()[i] = dict()
```

Answer (score 3):

As recommended [do not dynamiclly create variable from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354214/creating-dynamically-named-variables-from-user-input#answers)

---

This said, you may store this in a `dict` to store, then associate an empty dict for each key

```
result = {}
for idx in list1:
    result[idx] = {}

print(result)
# {'x': {}, 'y': {}, 'z': {}}
```

Comment: This will not create variables. It will give dictionary which is wrong as per his expected output. He wants variables with dict type.

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav I know, but as I wrote it's not recommended so I did not propose this idea, a dict that handle this is better

Comment: The question is what does the author expect it for. Offered way is better to solve the most problems. `Explicit is better than implicit`. It's about code generation where things can go much further than you expect. Python is not good option for it. Look at Lisp. But it's strongly opinion-based statement and not for this site, unfortunately.

Comment: @mrEvgenX *how can create empty dictionaries* is not very explicit that he waits for new variable, let's wait for the OP to give further details

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following code:

```
list1 = ["x","y","z"]
for i in list1:
    globals()[i] = dict()
```

This will give you:

```
x = {}
y = {}
z = {}
```

To check the output and its types you can do the following:

```
print(x)
print(type(x))
print(y)
print(type(y))
print(z)
print(type(z))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function.

For example, `exec("x=3")` creates the `x` variable, assigning to it the value `3`.

Your specific example can be solved like this:

```
for var in list1:
    exec(var + "={}")
```

Comment: Very dangerous, on my opinion. What if it will be the part of web-application and user can send a string `var` as `dumpDatabaseWithPasswords(); x`. For homework and five-lines scripts can be okay, but 99% cases it doesn't necessary.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Totally agree. It's not a good idea to dynamically create variables most of the times. I was simply trying to satisfy the *specific* needs of the user: he asked for a way to create new variables (I hope he won't use my answer as part of a web-application)

Answer (score 0):

This dynamic creation of variable names is not advised most of the time.
Check [Creating dynamically named variables from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354214/creating-dynamically-named-variables-from-user-input).

I am not sure what you are attempting to do but would this is a possible approach.

```
list1 = ["x","y","z"]
d = {}

for i in list1:
    d[i] = {}
```

You would get a dict with an empty dict inside for each of your strings.

Comment: This will not create variables. It will give dictionary which is wrong as per his expected output. He wants variables with dict type.

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav i know this does not return variables but maybe the question author does not really need variables and this could be enough.