# How do you make a new variable while a program is running in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python program where it asks the user for input and then creates a variable with the same name as the user output, like this:
Input: Hello
And then it creates a new variable called Hello. But if you print goodbye, it should create a new variable called goodbye. I tried googling it, but this question is very specific so I can't figure out how to google it well.I started my program like this:

```py
import cs50
input = get_string("Input: )
```

Then it's supposed to take the input and create a variable with the name [input]. Is there a way I can do this? If you know a way, please tell me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then revisit your question and show what you have tried and what problems you are having.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating dynamically named variables from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354214/creating-dynamically-named-variables-from-user-input).  Bottom line--don't do this. Chances are there are better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't dynamically create variables. Use a *container*, in this case, a dict maybe

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 's answer is the correct one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
user_input = input("Enter a variable name: ")
globals()[user_input]=25 #variable is dynamically created and is assigned to 25
```

so if the user inputs hello
check the above code using type(hello) and print(hello)

Answer (score 2):

Potentially you should consider making and using a dictionary, but to do exactly what you want you use the dictionary of the locals (or global) variables in a python script. You can access it by calling the function `locals()` (`globals()`). For example:

```py
locals()['Hello'] = 0
locals()['goodbye'] = 'some text'

print(Hello)
print(goodbye)
```

And the output is:

```
0
some text
```

For more info see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars)

Comment: `locals()` will not actually work in a local scope, only in a global scope, where `locals() is globals()`

Comment: Correct locals() will not work in all cases.

Comment: @Bharath to be precise, it doesn't work *whenever you are in a `local` scope*. Basically, there is no easy way to dynamically modify local variables

Comment: exactly, that's why i put the two of them, so he/she would know the existence of both options. Maybe i should specified this issue

Comment: Yes, i agree with you @juanpa.arrivillaga. That is what I wanted to say - perhaps I should have been more elaborate but I saw you already explained it adequately. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Create a dictionary variable in python and use this dictionary to dynamically create variables.

For example,  `myVars['Hello']='Hi'` is the same as `Hello='Hi'`

Comment: Pretty sure this is huge overkill for what the OP wants ... but hard to tell without their code.

Comment: agreed.. the question did not specify any constraints on the actual case either!

Comment: there is no global variable `__dict__`

Comment: edits made to the my answer.