# How to make a variable name dependant on input in python?

Tags: python, variables, input, points, voting

I need to create multiple variables based on int input so that if input is 5 then variables are created like: worker1, worker2, worker3, etc.

Is there any way in which I could generate variables like these and then add points to them dependant on the number chosen by the user?
Example:

How many workers?
10
-Choose worker
4
-added 1 point to worker4

Comment: No, just use a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating dynamically named variables from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354214/creating-dynamically-named-variables-from-user-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple variables, you can use a dictionary. Using multiple variables is less Pythonic than using a dictionary and can prove cumbersome with large data. In your example, you could use a dictionary to store each worker and their number of points.
Documentation for dictionaries can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

For example:

```
#recieve a valid input for the number of workers
while True:
    num = input("How many workers would you like to create?\n") # accepts an int
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Must input an integer")
    else:
        break

#create a dictionary with the workers and their scores (0 by default)
workers = {'worker'+str(i+1) : 0 for i in range(num)}

# get the user to choose a worker, and add 1 to their score
while True:
    worker = input("Which worker would you like to add a point to?\n") #accepts worker e.g worker1 or worker5
    if worker in workers:
        workers[worker] += 1
        print(f"Added one point to {worker}")
        break
    else:
        print("That is not a worker")

print(workers)
```

This code gets a user input to create a certain number of workers. It then gets user input to add a point to one of the workers. You can change this to add multiple points to different workers, but this is just a basic example, and it depends on what you want to do with it.