# How to create a list of variables that differ from each other with only last character in python

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have a lot of identical variables that differ only with the last character

```
b1 = Class(argument)
b2 = Class(argument)
b3 = Class(argument)
b4 = Class(argument)
b5 = Class(argument)
b6 = Class(argument)
```

Is there a way to create them in a loop or somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799446/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-local-variables-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary for this purpose

```
d = {}
for i in range(1, 7):
    d['b' + str(i)] = Class(argument)
```

Comment: @twasbrillig obviously! I hope you got the idea!

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in xrange(1,7):exec("b%d=Class(argument)" % i)
```

Then you can check with:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(locals())
```

Comment: So I made this: `for i in range(1,7):exec("b%d=Class(argument)" % i)` - changed xrange() to range(). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a list

```
b = []
for i in range(1,7):
    b.append(Class(argument))
```

or

```
b = [Class() for x in range(1,7)]
```