# How to update local variables in function with a dictionary?

Tags: python

A problem meeted in rewriting a python program.

I move some previous global variables into a dictionay, so I have to rewrite the functions which have used those variables.

For example,

```
#old one
a, b = 1, 2    
def func(c):
    print a+b+c

#new one
d = dict(a=1,b=2)
def func(c,d):
    a = d['a']
    b = d['b']
    print a+b+c
```

As the *dictionary d* is large, so I'm seeking a something like this

```
d = dict(a=1,b=2)
def func(c,d):
    locals().update(d)
    print a+b+c
```

I have tried  `__dict__.update(d)`, however `__dict__` can't be accessed directly.

Or `for key,value in d.items():
    setattr(obj,key,value)`
is possible? If yes, how to set the obj to the function itself?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `d['a']`, `d['b']`, etc? Or in other words, how is doing this going to help you with anything?

Comment: How about using eval?  `print eval('a+b+c',globals(),dict(d,c=c))`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python / Basically you *can* do this on python2, but not python3, but you *shouldn't* do it at all.

Comment: @VaughnCato That's not going to modify locals.

Comment: @korylprince: No, but the dictionary becomes the locals, which may be all that is needed.

Comment: @korylprince Because d has many keys, it's a lot of work to change each var to d['var']. Thanks for your usefull discussion, sorry for my ambiguous question :) .  `exec` or `eval` seems to be a good solution, maybe I could use  Decorator to wrap the function with few modifications.

Comment: Maybe your editor has an option to "rename" the local variables to the dict-key pair?

Comment: @substructure Just iterate through `d.items()`. That yields (key,value) pairs.

Comment: @korylprince Thanks. However, I want to use these items separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create local variables programmatically in that way.

Instead, just use the dictionary directly by accessing its keys.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do instead is to evaluate your expression using the dictionary as the local variables:

```
def func(c,d):
    print eval('a+b+c',globals(),dict(d,c=c))

func(3,dict(a=1,b=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **`in` clause of an `exec` statement**. In the `in` clause you may provide namespace(s) for Python to search when executing a string. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt)

---

For example:

```
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> def func(c,d):
        exec 'print a+b+c' in d, locals()


>>> func(5,d)
8
```