# How to get unknown local variable to other namespace

Tags: python, python-3.4

I want to read some input, which contains python assignment statements like this string:

```
"VARIABLE = 'something' + OTHER_VAR"
```

So I use one of these:

```
exec("VARIABLE = 'something' + OTHER_VAR")
exec("VARIABLE = 'something' + OTHER_VAR", globals(), locals())
```

I want to use this variable in other code, but after exec(...) it is not in current namespace. 
It is possible to get the variable value like this:

```
locals()['VARIABLE']
```

however, if I dont know the name of variable it is not solution for me.

So how to get that new variable into my namespace?

**UPDATE:**
My data for exec are like this:

```
COMPBLOCK =  StringLeft(MyPlatform.HierarchicalName,6) +"_IADI." + CMP + "." + BLOCK ;
SetCustomPropertyValue("DEVLM2",COMPBLOCK + ".DEVLM2",false);
SetCustomPropertyValue("CRIT",COMPBLOCK + ".CRIT",false);
SetCustomPropertyValue("UNACK",COMPBLOCK + ".UNACK",false);
SetCustomPropertyValue("ALMSTA_26",COMPBLOCK + ".ALMSTA#B26",false);
```

I defined functions `SetCustomPropertyValue` and `StringLeft`. I want to avoid some complicated translation of this script to python with all possible inputs. `Exec()` seems to be very quick solution, but after reading [this post - Modifying locals in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python) I am little bit stuck.

Comment: Why is this a problem in the first place? What is the context for evaluating arbitrary Python expressions here?

Comment: What do you mean by *your namespace*? `locals()` *is* the local namespace. Something like `exec("a = 5"); print(a);` works, i.e. `a` is then in the local namespace. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `exec`ing arbitrary strings is dangerous. Are you sure you _really_ want to do this?

Comment: here is the problem: if i execute above code in console, it works (VARIABLE is define). But if I make a function like `def fn(line): exec(line) print(VARIABLE)` I got `NameError: 'VARIABLE' is not defined`

Comment: your function `fn` has a different *local* namespace (that's the point of local namespaces...)

Comment: print statement is inside this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issues around `locals()` in Python 3 (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python)) so generally speaking, changes in `locals()` during runtime is not allowed.

So I made some workaround, where I defined my own namespace dictonary `my_dict_locals` and `my_dict_globals`. To `my_dict_globals` I copied some necessary definitions from current namespace (like `SetCustomPropertyValue` function definition ...). Then I just called

```
exec(each, my_dict_globals, my_dict_locals)
```

where `each` could be like one of following:

```
COMPBLOCK =  StringLeft(MyPlatform.HierarchicalName,6) +"_IADI." + CMP + "." + BLOCK ;
SetCustomPropertyValue("DEVLM2",COMPBLOCK + ".DEVLM2",false);
SetCustomPropertyValue("CRIT",COMPBLOCK + ".CRIT",false);
SetCustomPropertyValue("UNACK",COMPBLOCK + ".UNACK",false);
SetCustomPropertyValue("ALMSTA_26",COMPBLOCK + ".ALMSTA#B26",false);`
```

This works for me as I expected and I have in `my_dict_locals` all variables from above script defined.

Answer (score 1):

1. pay attention to the comments warning about how dangerous it is to execute arbitrary code from a foreign source.
2. if the statements have a consistent format, for example like the one in the example, you could easly parse it and extract the variable name:

   ```
   varname = stmt.split('=')[0].strip()
   ```

   or something more sophisticated using regular expressions
3. if the statement always introduces exactly one new variable, you could compare `locals()` before and after execution and check which new variable has been added:

   ```
   old_locals = set(locals().keys())
   exec(stmt)
   new_locals = set(locals().keys())
   varname = (new_locals-old_locals).pop()
   ```

Comment: Yes, this is good solution for this, however, I also have other types of statements, like: `SetCustomPropertyValue('DEVLM2',COMPBLOCK + '.DEVLM2',False);`. I defined function SetCustomPropertyValue, it can read the variables, but, it cannot see the resulting variable. (In this case, this could be translated to `DEVLM2 = COMPBLOCK + '.DEVLM2'`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a small domain specific language as found in [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to declare your new variables? 
This way you don't need to run untrusted code, and get simple things like variable expansion (though probably in a slightly different syntax).

E.g. considering the following input

```
FOO = world
BAR = hello, @FOO@
```

as simple parser could look like:

```
lines=["FOO = world", "BAR = hello, @FOO@" ]
vars={}

# store variables in dictionary, with expansion
for line in lines:
  key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.split('=', 1)]
  for k in vars:
     value=value.replace('@%s@' % (k), str(vars[k]))
  vars[key]=value
# make variables available in local namespace
for k in vars:
    locals()[k]=vars[k]
## use new variable
print(BAR)
```