# python: **kwargs to variables

Tags: python, function, input

In a function `def test(**params)`, how do I use the keys of `**params` to create variables named by `kwargs.keys()` with values `kwargs.values()` that I can use inside of my function `test`?

Comment: Why not just use `params['keyname']`? Why do you need separate local variables? You can't dynamically add new local names to a function body.

Comment: Even if you did that, say they call `test(foo=3)` and you make a `foo` local variable initialized to `3`. Unless the body of `test` already uses `foo`, you basically can't do anything with this variable, and if it *does* already use `foo`, why didn't you define a regular `foo` argument instead of just `**params`?

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT: This approach doesn't work in most circumstances. I tested it in IPython where it does work in the outer context.**

You should just use the kwargs `__get__` lookup. It is bad practice to do this,

~~but if you insist on creating these variables you can do: `locals().update(kwargs)`. Doing this makes this code valid:~~

```
def foo(**kwargs):
   locals().update(kwargs)
   return a + 3

print(foo(a=3))
```

~~will output 6~~

will output NameError: name 'a' is not defined

---

**EDIT: This works**

I'm actually quite surprised that updating locals doesn't work in the standard interpreter. I also found that eval doesn't work either. I've been using tricks like this in IPython for years. Looking at [Modifying locals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python) it seems like you used to be able to do this in Python 2 using exec, but its no longer valid in Python 3 (which is probably a good thing).

However, I have found a hack that I believe works. Again, please don't do this in practice.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    foo.__globals__.update(kwargs)
    return a + 3

print(foo(a=3))
```

Comment: Yet again, I must point out that [no, this doesn't actually work](http://ideone.com/XT1WzC).

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#locals): "Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: Yes, but this now pollutes the *global scope*. Also, modifying `locals` doesn't work in IPython either, so I'm not sure what behavior you've been seeing.

Comment: @juanp.arrivillaga modifying locals will work in IPython if you are in the namespace of the interactive terminal. It doesn't work in function definitions though.