# python3: Pythonic analogue to C-preprocessor macros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, python-decorators, preprocessor-directive

In my python3 code, I have a series of functions into which I want to insert some common code. This code must set the same set of local variables within each function.

To better explain, consider the following function ...

```
def arbtrary_function(arg0, arg1):
    ### I want these local variables set ...
    localvar0  = some_function_of(arg0)
    localvar1  = some_other_function_of(arg0)
    # ... 18 more similar settings ...
    localvar20 = yet_another_function_of(arg0)
    ### End of local variable settings
    # The rest of the function's code will use
    # these local variables.
```

I want to begin a number of functions with this same code block.

I have tried doing this with a decorator, but I haven't been able to figure out how the decorator can set local variable values within the function that it is decorating.

If python3 had something like the C-preprocessor's macro facility, I could do this:

```
### Somehow define a "macro" with those 21 lines of common code ...
somehow_define_macro COMMON_CODE(ARG):
    localvar0  = some_function_of(ARG)
    localvar1  = some_other_function_of(ARG)
    # ... 18 more similar settings ...
    localvar20 = yet_another_function_of(ARG)
```

... and then, I could do this in each of the many functions into which I'd like to insert this common code:

```
def arbtrary_function(arg0, arg1):
    COMMON_CODE(arg0)
```

But, of course, python doesn't have this C-preprocessor functionality.

I tried to do this with a function that accepts its caller's `locals()` dictionary as an argument. Even though the function makes changes to that supplied `locals()` dictionary, those changes don't make any new local variables available to the caller after the function returns. For example:

```
def modifylocals(loc, arg):
    loc['localvar0'] = some_function_of(arg)
    # ... etc. ...

def arbitrary_function(arg0, arg1):
    modifylocals(locals(), arg0)
    # The following properly prints the new value of localvar0
    # that was set within locals() ...
    print('value in locals() of localvar0: {}' \
        .format(locals().get('localvar0', 'NOT SET')))
    # However, the localvar0 local variable does not get created
    # within my function. The following prints 'DOES NOT EXIST' ...
    try:
        print('value of localvar0: {}'.format(localvar0))
    except:
        print('DOES NOT EXIST')
```

I know I could also do the following, but then, I would have to change each function that calls the `setmylocals()` function if I ever want that function to set more or fewer local variables ...

```
def setmylocals(arg):
    localvar0  = some_function_of(arg)
    # ... etc. ...
    localvar20 = yet_another_function_of(arg)
    return (localvar0, ... etc. ..., localvar20)

def arbitrary_function(arg0, arg1):
    localvar0, ..., localvar20 = setmylocals(arg0)
```

Does anyone know of a way I can implement this particular C-preprocessor-like functionality in python3?

PS: I know that if I refactor all the functions that use these local variables to use dictionary entries instead of the local variables in question, then this becomes a straightforward task. However, the functions I want to modify already exist in a large code base, and I don't want to refactor all of those functions. Being able to optionally pre-set local variable values in this "C-preprocessor-like" manner involves much less work and will have much less impact on the existing code base.

In other words, I could do this, but I don't want to ...

```
def setvariables(arg):
    retval = {}
    retval['localvar0'] = some_function_of(arg)
    # ... etc. ...
    return retval

def arbitrary_function(arg0, arg1):
    vars = setvariables(arg0)
    # ... and then change the rest of the code to use
    # `vars['localvar0']` instead of `localvar0`, etc.
    # However, I want to avoid all this refactoring
    # of the existing code.
```

PPS: This discussion states that what I'm looking for is impossible:
[Modifying locals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/modifying-locals-in-python)

But hope springs eternal. Does anyone know of ***any*** procedure for doing what I want?

Comment: I thought of an approach that might work. I could extend importer and write my own `loader.get_data` as described in __PEP 302__ (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/). That modified method would feed any file-based python code through the __filepp__ processor (http://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Edm26/filepp/) or something similar. I will work on this and report back here later.

Comment: Sounds you are dealing with some large legacy code.  If you can not refactor the old code, adding another layer like the above most likely will make things worse – especially in the long run, when the next programmer come along and needs to update the code you are considering.  Given that 'Explicit is better than implicit' I would strongly suggest you go with the setmylocals variation.  Working with a dict of function versions and the unpacking generalizations (PEP448) should get you a long way.  When it comes to Python 'import this' is often good to reflect on.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the PEP 448 unpacking generalizations. That's probably the best compromise. I'll post my solution here in a little while.