# How to change a variable by its name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic

I can change a variable by it's name using globals():

```
k = 2 
def intercommunicationstep(xname, value):
    globals()[xname]=value
    return 1 - q**(k-1)

q = 0.2  
print(intercommunicationstep('k',1))
```

but for some reason the code is not working with locals() or vars():

```
def intercommunicationstep(xname, value):
    k = 2
    locals()[xname]=value
    print(locals())
    return 1 - q**(k-1)

q = 0.2 
print(intercommunicationstep('k',1))
```

it outputs 0.8 instead of 1.
I don't want to bother global variables, and prefer to handle this inside function, but alas, I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Use a class instead.

Comment: what are you even trying to achieve by doing this? wouldn't `k = intercommunicationstep(k, 1)` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically set local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable)

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like it's possible for optimization reasons : [Any way to modify locals dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/any-way-to-modify-locals-dictionary).

If you absolutely need to have access to variables by key, you should probably create a dictionary inside of your function instead.