# hasattr with functions

Tags: python, attributes, hasattr

How to check attr existence in function or method with `hasattr` (or without)?
When I try to check it is False in any way:

```
>>> def f():
        at = True


>>> hasattr(f, 'at')
False
>>> hasattr(f(), 'at')
False
```

Comment: What do you hope to do with the information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables are not attributes. You cannot use any `*attr()` to frob them.

Comment: +1. @I159: if you *really* want to see what local variables a function is using, [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360721/how-to-get-set-local-variables-of-a-function-from-outside-in-python) is out there, but what on earth would be your use case?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, look at below example.

```
>>> def f():
...    f.at = True
...
>>> hasattr(f, 'at')
False
>>> f()
>>> hasattr(f, 'at')
True
```