# How to get types of attributes of a class object without initializing it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

**Pre-Info**

We have a structure running on multiple machines which are communicating each other by using our json serializable objects to carry data between devices.

I am trying to create documentation for these classes by using markdown.

**Problem**

```python
class BaseParams(JsonObject):
    """ default values for all classes"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.param0: str = "test"


class ExampleParams(BaseParams):
    """ example class for data container"""

    def __init__(self, param1: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.param1: str = param1
        self.param2: int = 0
```

I have many classes like *ExampleParams* in a py file. I collected them, their docs etc.  dynamically with help of *inspect* and *importlib* modules but i also have to collect their params and params's types.

Trying to get something like that:

```python
resultdict = {
    "ExampleParams":{"param0":"str","param1":"str","param2":"int"}
}
```

How can i do that **without initializing** the classes?

**PS1:** It is easy when i initialize them but there are many classes and every one have different initialize values. So i have to do it without initializing them i guess.

**PS2:** Every atrribute's type is declared by typing module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without initialization local params like `param0` and `param2` are [not evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361058/9632441), so Python interpreter has no information about their existence or type.

The only possibility you have is to collect arguments of `__init__` method. Using your example structure:

```py
import inspect

params = []
for parent in ExampleParams.mro()[::-1]:
    parent_init = inspect.getfullargspec(parent.__init__)
    # parent_init.annotations contains annotations if specified in method signature
    for param in parent_init.args:
        if param == 'self':
            continue
        params.append(param)
```

`params = ['param1']` in your case.

Comment: i have to collect param0, param1, and param 2 too, otherwise it is meaningless.

Comment: You can look into `ExampleParams.__init__.__code__` to see all the information interpreter has about `__init__`. For example, `ExampleParams.__init__.__code__.co_names` contains all variable names in local scope.
I think the only option is to write python file parser to extract the information of interest.

Comment: still i cant reach param0, i guess i will use init with help of `paramsclass.__init__.__code__.co_argcount` but getting type hints of attributes still remains

Comment: `param0` can be reached only by traversing class `mro`. Type hints are, again, only available for `__init__` arguments, through `inspect.getfullargspec(ExampleParams.__init__).annotations`

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted but it seems like it is the only solution